# WCF RoutingService not routing wsDualHttpBinding with callbacks

Tags: wcf, routes, callback

I´m having problems using the .Net 4.0 Routing Service connecting to a service using callbacks. To my understanding both binding and callbacks are supported by the Routing Service. Service and Client alone are operating fine.

What I did, was taking the MS WCF and WF Samples located here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en

and changed the configuration to match the binding of my service. I can call operations via the routing service from the client to the service, only callbacks from service to the client are not received by the client.

The routing service is configured as follows, using a console application as a host

```cs
using (ServiceHost serviceHost =
            new ServiceHost(typeof(RoutingService)))
        {
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<services>
  <!--ROUTING SERVICE -->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="routingData" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService" >
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add  baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/routingservice/router"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpoint"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"
              bindingConfiguration="UnSecureBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="routingData">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <routing filterTableName="routingTable1" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UnSecureBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint name="NotificationService"
            address="http://localhost/CommServices/NotificationService.svc"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="UnSecureBinding"
            contract="*" />
</client>
<!--ROUTING SECTION -->
<routing>
  <filters>
    <filter name="MatchAllFilter1" filterType="MatchAll" />
  </filters>
  <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="routingTable1">
        <add filterName="MatchAllFilter1" endpointName="NotificationService" />
    </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
```

If I enabling ServiceModel tracing, I can see an ArgumentException deep in the WCF Stack, a trace I´havent followed so far.

Can anyone give a hint into the right direction, or correct me If my assumptions concerning the callback capabilities of the RoutingService are wrong.

TIA & Cheers
Dominik

Comment: How did you configure your routing service? Don't expect that people will download anything to understand your question. Modify your question and add configuration of the routing service.

Comment: Hi Ladislav and thanks for the remark, upated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone stumbles like I did, the problem was the contract on the router endpoint. RequestReplyRouter does not support callbacks but IDuplexSessionRouter does.

```xml
<endpoint address=""
              binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpoint"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IDuplexSessionRouter"
              bindingConfiguration="UnSecureBinding"/>
```

Regards
Dominik

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the issue I expected ... :)